# Getting nested objects with Active Record Join without includes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an Active Record query that involves a JOIN using a SQL statement.

```
TableA.where(:b_id => "123")
      .joins("INNER JOIN TableB ON column1='value1' AND column2 = TableB.id")
```

where *column1* and *column2* belong to TableA

The reason I have to use SQL is because I don't have a relationship defined between the two tables (for other reasons), and haven't found a way to specify a ON clause on columns, using Active Record JOIN

Since I don't have a relationship defined, I cannot use *:includes* and hence do not have access to TableB's columns in the results.
Is there a way to get TableB's data by modifying the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the columns in the [**`select`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) query.

```
TableA.select('TableA.*, TableB.column1, TableB.column2')
      .where(:b_id => "123")
      .joins("INNER JOIN TableB ON column1='value1' AND column2 = TableB.id")
```

NOTE: You might not see the columns in the `TableA` record in rails console. Use `as_json` to check if you got them in result

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Didn't realize I could use TableB's columns in the select.